# Check if Heroku Proximo has changed the ip address

Tags: heroku, proximo

Is there a way to check if Heroku changed the static ip which we get by using proximo add on?

Comment: You can go to http://proximo-api.herokuapp.com/dashboard and see what the Static IP is there